# How to mock Symfony 2 service in a functional test?

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, mocking, phpunit

I have symfony service which uses redis connection in some methods but not in all methods.

```
class ServiceA
{
    private $redis;

    public function __construct($redis)
    {
        $this->redis = $redis;
    }

    public function getRequest($param1, $param2)
    {
    $result = $param1+ $param2;
        return $request;
    }

    .. other methods which use $redis connection
}
```

I am writing functional test for the code which use only getRequest method (this method does not need redis connection) but as the constructor takes the connection as an argument, when I run test it tried to connect redis server.

How can I write mock service which does not use  redis connection at all and ignore original constructor.

I am trying approach mentioned below but no success. It still tries to connect redis eventhough I have disabled original constructor.

http://blog.lyrixx.info/2013/04/12/symfony2-how-to-mock-services-during-functional-tests.html

```
$serviceA = $this->getMockBuilder('ServiceA')
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->getMock();

static::$kernel->getContainer()->set('my_bundle.service.a', $serviceA);
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

After you create `ServiceA` mock, you need to pass it to client's container (not the one from kernel's because client object builds its own kernel). Try this:

```
$client = self::createClient();

$serviceA = $this->getMockBuilder('ServiceA')
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->getMock();

$client->getContainer()->set('my_bundle.service.a', $serviceA);
```

Pay attention, that you must inject this mocked service every time you make a request. It's because the client rebuilds kernel between each two requests.

Comment: Emphase on the "you need to pass it to the client's container (not the one from kernel)".

Comment: Does  `$client->getContainer()->set('my_bundle.service.a', $serviceA)` imply that `$container->get()` will not instantiate the service anymore? We want  to "override" the service but still want the container to inject the service its dependencies afterwards.

Comment: No, it won't instantiate the service anymore once you set the object by "set" method. You need to take care of it by yourself.

Answer (score 6):

You should not mock your tested class, you should mock the Redis class and inject it.

If Redis isn't used for this test, you need not even configure the mock.

```
$redis = $this->getMockBuilder('Redis')->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();
$serviceA = new ServiceA($redis);
```

Answer (score 4):

There is special tool which takes care of mocked services - https://github.com/ramunasd/symfony-container-mocks

It's easy like that:

```
$service = static::$kernel->getContainer()->prophesize('my.custom.service');
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ?

```
$serviceA = $this->getMock('ServiceA', array('getRequest'), array(), '', false);
```