# Symfony Phpunit keeps using actual class instead of mock

Tags: symfony, mocking, phpunit

I'm using Symfony 6.4.4, php 8.2.5
My class depends on other class, that sends http requests to microservice. For testing purposes I want to mock this class.

Code structure:

```
interface GatewayServiceInterface
{
    public function sendRequest(): int;
}

class GatewayService implements GatewayServiceInterface
{
    public function sendRequest(): int;
}


final readonly class TestedClass
{
    public function __construct(
      private GatewayServiceInterface $gatewayService,
      private SomeClassA $someClassA,
      private SomeClassB $someClassB
    ) {}
}
```

So now I want to test `TestedClass`. And I want it to use mock of `GatewayServiceInterface`.
Here is what I do

```
final class TestedClassTest extends WebTestCase

public function setUp(): void
{
    parent::setUp();

    $gatewayServiceMock = $this->createMock(GatewayServiceInterface::class);
    $gatewayServiceMock->method->('sendRequest')->willReturn(200);

    $testedClassWithMock = new TestedClass(
      $gatewayServiceMock,
      $this->container->get(SomeClassA::class),
      $this->container->get(SomeClassB::class)
    )

    $this->container->set(
      TestedClass::class,
      $testedClassWithMock
    );

/** Run some tests with TestedClass */
}
```

But when I run tests it still uses regular GatewayServiceInterface instead of MockObject.
Based on what I read on this site and symfony docs my code should work. What can I do wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is here [How to mock Symfony 2 service in a functional test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726281/how-to-mock-symfony-2-service-in-a-functional-test/19726963#19726963).

My mistake was that I was using Kernel's container instead of Client's container